# Asymptotic values of Meromorphic map

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

$f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z+1}$

I know that $0$ and $\infty$ are two asymptotic values of the above function.
Question:Does there exist another asymptotic values other than $0$ and $\infty$ ?

Comment: what have you tried so far? what definition of "Asymptotic values" are you using?

Comment: we know omitted values implies asymptotic values

Comment: we know omitted values implies asymptotic values , $0$, $\infty$ are two omitted values

Comment: well, there are no other singularities than $z=-1$, so there are no other asymptotic values

Comment: There's another singularity at infinity. A big nasty one

Comment: @SatyajitSahoo Saying omitted values imply asymptotic values does not answer the question. What do you mean by "asymptotic value", exactly?